# Rails: How to add HTTP AUTH at custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, puma

How to add HTTP AUTH at custom controller action?

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #NO AUTH
  end

  def custom
    #I NEED HTTP AUTH ONLY HERE
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get 'my/custom', to: 'my#custom'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: [:custom]

  def custom
    #I NEED HTTP AUTH ONLY HERE
  end
end
```

You can also call the auth directly in the action:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def custom
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "dhh" && password == "secret"
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

Here are the docs for more advanced usage: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [http_basic_authenticate_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) method. I have passed the :custom symbol to the :only option, which means the authentication will only apply to that method.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "username", password: "password", only: :custom

  def index
    #NO AUTH
  end

  def custom
    #I NEED HTTP AUTH ONLY HERE
  end
end
```